# ImageSharp convert Rgb to Hsv

Tags: imagesharp

Using ImageSharp 1.0.0-alpha-000095, it's easy to convert Rgb to Hsv, using the public implicit operator between Color and Hsv.

However, with ImageSharp 1.0.0-beta0001, the Hsv struct is now internal, so I cannot convert Rgba32 into Hsv.

What's the proper way to load an Image, get a pixel, and convert it to Hsv ?

Answer (score 2):

That's a very, very old alpha. Color translation has been internal for a long time.

We're currently replacing the implicit conversion with a full color conversion library. When that is finished you will be easily able to convert from one colorspace to another.

In the interim I can only suggest building something custom based on the classes found in the Github repository.

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/blob/68d32a7ec09a4b03de0d021f575b34458ed605e5/src/ImageSharp/ColorSpaces/Conversion/Implementation/Hsv/HsvAndRgbConverter.cs

Comment: Hi James - I wondered this was ever made to work? I am looking at that link you provided there but I don't know where to start?

Comment: There's an open, work-in-progress PR tp finish off the API for bulk conversion and make the conversion methods public. We'll have them available soon.

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/664

Comment: This is impressive work! Thanks for the update - currently using Emgu.CV but will adopt ImageSharp.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!